# Unable to scrape table in dynamic multitab website using rvest

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest, rselenium

### my objective

The objective of my code is to scrape the information in the *Characteristics* tab of the following url, preferably as a data frame

```r
URL <- "https://plants.sc.egov.usda.gov/home/plantProfile?symbol=ACPL"
```

as it is shown in the following screenshot

[image]

For that I would usually use the *rvest* package but of what I have read in some other links I might also need the *RSelenium* package.

```r
library(rvest)
library(RSelenium)
```

### What I have tried so far

#### Getting the element using rvest’s html_elements

In order to do that I am using the [SelectorGadget](https://selectorgadget.com/) add on in firefox, and when I select the table I get the following:

[image]

So naturally I tried something like this:

```r
Test <- rvest::read_html(URL)

Test2 <- Test %>% 
  rvest::html_elements("section")
```

The two objects come as following:

```r
str(Test)
# List of 2
#  $ node:<externalptr> 
#  $ doc :<externalptr> 
#  - attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "xml_document" "xml_node"
```

and

```r
str(Test2)
#  list()
#  - attr(*, "class")= chr "xml_nodeset"
length(Test2)
# [1] 0
```

Which is an empty list, and I am not sure of what I am doing wrong there. Looking at several other

#### Dynamic tabpanel?

Looking a bit more into thiss, it looks like this is a dynamic page and that I would have to “activate”(if that is the right word), the panel programatically.

[image]

and it seems there is where RSelenium comes in handy, I am still trying to figure that package out, so I will post updates to this question if there is no answers when I figure it out.

Session info

```r
sessioninfo::session_info()
# ─ Session info ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#  setting  value                       
#  version  R version 4.1.0 (2021-05-18)
#  os       Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS          
#  system   x86_64, linux-gnu           
#  ui       X11                         
#  language (EN)                        
#  collate  en_US.UTF-8                 
#  ctype    en_US.UTF-8                 
#  tz       America/Santiago            
#  date     2021-06-11                  
# 
# ─ Packages ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#  package     * version  date       lib source        
#  askpass       1.1      2019-01-13 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#  assertthat    0.2.1    2019-03-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#  binman        0.1.2    2020-10-02 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#  bitops        1.0-7    2021-04-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#  caTools       1.18.2   2021-03-28 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#  cli           2.5.0    2021-04-26 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#  curl          4.3.1    2021-04-30 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#  digest        0.6.27   2020-10-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#  evaluate      0.14     2019-05-28 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#  fs            1.5.0    2020-07-31 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#  glue          1.4.2    2020-08-27 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#  highr         0.9      2021-04-16 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#  htmltools     0.5.1.1  2021-01-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#  httr          1.4.2    2020-07-20 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#  knitr         1.33     2021-04-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#  lifecycle     1.0.0    2021-02-15 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#  magrittr      2.0.1    2020-11-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#  mime          0.10     2021-02-13 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#  openssl       1.4.4    2021-04-30 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#  png           0.1-7    2013-12-03 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#  R6            2.5.0    2020-10-28 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#  Rcpp          1.0.6    2021-01-15 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#  reprex        2.0.0    2021-04-02 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#  rlang         0.4.11   2021-04-30 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#  rmarkdown     2.8      2021-05-07 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#  RSelenium   * 1.7.7    2020-02-03 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#  rstudioapi    0.13     2020-11-12 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#  rvest       * 1.0.0    2021-03-09 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#  semver        0.2.0    2017-01-06 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#  sessioninfo   1.1.1    2018-11-05 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#  stringi       1.6.2    2021-05-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#  stringr       1.4.0    2019-02-10 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#  wdman         0.2.5    2020-01-31 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#  withr         2.4.2    2021-04-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#  xfun          0.23     2021-05-15 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#  XML           3.99-0.6 2021-03-16 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#  xml2          1.3.2    2020-04-23 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#  yaml          2.2.1    2020-02-01 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
# 
# [1] /home/derek/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1
# [2] /usr/local/lib/R/site-library
# [3] /usr/lib/R/site-library
# [4] /usr/lib/R/library
```

Comment: The data is retrieved from a series of JSON files.  Using the developers tools menu item from your browser, look at the network tab and filter for "XHR" files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data is dynamically retrieved from an API call. You can retrieve direct from that url and simplify the json returned to get a dataframe:

```
library(jsonlite)

data <- jsonlite::read_json('https://plantsservices.sc.egov.usda.gov/api/PlantCharacteristics/92843', simplifyVector = T)
```

You need to pick up that id on the end however to make this re-usable:

```
library(jsonlite)

id <- jsonlite::read_json('https://plantsservices.sc.egov.usda.gov/api/PlantProfile?symbol=ACPL')$Id
data <- jsonlite::read_json(paste0('https://plantsservices.sc.egov.usda.gov/api/PlantCharacteristics/', id), simplifyVector = T)
```